PostgreSQL caching table from "dotnet sql-cache" command
I have tried to create a cache table by using dotnet sql-cache create. i want to create a cache table for PostgreSQL. i did not find any resources about connection string for cache table, here is example for SQL-Server
dotnet sql-cache create `Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=CacheDb` dbo DataCache"

This command taken from "Pro ASP.NET Core" by Adam Freeman. how to create cache table by using dotnet sql-cache create? Additionally, as i understand cache is data that being stored in RAM, but what is the purpose of storing cache data again in DB if it will not give any advantage in performance.

What problem are you trying to solve by using a cache table?

" but what is the purpose of storing cache data again in DB if it will not give any advantage in performance" -> 1) you can share the cache between multiple servers 2) who said that what is being cached isn't very costly to compute?

dotnet sql-cache is intended for use with SQL Server, not PostgreSQL; you can check the code to check that. This maps to the code used by Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.
As for the why question; out of process cache servers have advantages of:

cold start (you don't lose the cache when your app server restarts)
clusters (multiple app servers sharing a cache)
capacity (app servers are often low-spec, scaled "out"; a dedicated cache server might scale "up" rather than "out")

There are trade-offs too, of course.
Note that you might also try Redis (or Garnet) as an out-of-process cache server; easier to setup, and generally more scalable in this scenario.
